# .htaccess: how to restrict access to a single file by IP?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, apache2, apache2.2

I've look all over, but keeps running into same info that talks about directory level IP restriction, which usually looks something like this:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 123.123.123.123
```

Is it possible to have same type of access restriction tied to a page/document?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This will allow either someone from IP 127.0.0.1 *or* logged as a valid user. Stick it either in your  config or .htaccess file.

```
    <Files learn.php>
        Satisfy any
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.1

        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "private"
        AuthUserFile /var/www/phpexperts.pro/.htpasswd
        AuthGroupFile /dev/null
        Require valid-user
    </Files>
```

IP Alone:

```
    <Files learn.php>
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
    </Files>
```

That definitely answers your question.

Comment: Fastest answer response ever!

Comment: @TheodoreR.Smith : if I want to deny from one IP but allow from all others then what to write in htaccess?

Comment: Change to `Allow from all` `Deny from IP_ADDRESS`.

Comment: @TheodoreR.Smith, I tried your code but I am getting Access forbidden!  from my ip address. I have to access the service.php page from my single ip.  <Files service.php>
        Order deny, allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 0.0.0.0
    </Files> https://prnt.sc/vtkknw

Answer (score 9):

I think the directive needs to be:

```
Order deny,allow
```

for the answer above to work (at least for the IP Alone solution).

Comment: How to block an organization to open my website from their PCs ? They have 10 PCs connected on LAN and they need to access my website from only 5 of their PCs and block on the other 5? How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Mod-rewrite based solution :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^Y\.O\.U\.R\.IP$
RewriteRule ^file\.php$ - [F,L]
```

The rewriteRule above will deny all requests to **file.php** if client ip does not match the ip address in the RewriteCond's pattern

Comment: This answer is not clear to implement for many developers.

Comment: @landed Could you please explain what's not clear in my answer? This is a mod-rewrite solution to protect a file from an ip address and it's the easiest , fastest,and safest way to do so.

Answer (score 1):

For a more up to date Apache 2.4 example:

```
<Files file.html>
    Require ip 123.123.123.123
</Files>
```

Here are the more in depth docs for additional options and examples: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html and the docs for the `<Files>` directive: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#files

> Note that `<Files>` can be nested inside `<Directory>` sections to restrict the portion of the filesystem they apply to.

Comment: is this still current?