# Deny all access to a file but one ip | htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I tried the following but DOESNT work(no body can access the file including the IP that i want it to access)

```
<Files something.php>
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
allow from zzz.zzz.zzz.zzz
</Files>
```

I want to deny the access to a file to all the world except one ip, how do i do this?
Thanks

Comment: I am really sorry but I am new to this, do you mean in the .htaccess file?

Comment: It does not seem to be anything wrong with that set of rules. ¿What is your question?

Comment: my question is the code doesnt work for me, if you say the code works for you, what would be the reason that doesnt work for me.... :S, thanks!!

Comment: The code should be in the .htaccess file at the directory where something.php is.

Comment: both of them are in the same directory

Comment: Is `.htaccess` enabled on your server? Do other `.htaccess` directives work? How is it failing? (Everyone can access the file? Nobody can access the file?)

Comment: no body can access the file including the IP that i want it to access

Comment: Try with a range, like this: `allow from 192.168.0.0/33` or with a domain name, like this: `allow from .*domain\.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer in an older post, one of the answers in here: [.htaccess: how to restrict access to a single file by IP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604526/htaccess-how-to-restrict-access-to-a-single-file-by-ip?rq=1), the correct is:

```
 <Files something.php>
 Order deny, allow
 Deny from all
 allow from zzz.zzz.zzz.zzz
</Files>
```

from the original I changed "Order allow, deny" to "Order deny, allow" and it works!

Answer (score 1):

The reason it did not work is because your `Deny` directive overrode your `Allow` directive.
What `Order Allow,Deny` does is:

1. Evaluate `Allow`, flag "allow" if any matched.
2. Evaluate `Deny`, flag "deny" if any matched (even if previously matched by `Allow`)
3. Evaluate flag. If flag is not set, deny it.

So, it is **required** that you **remove** `Deny from All` if you do not want all requests to be Denied. Just a note for MickeyRoush's answer.

As for `Order Deny,Allow`, it's the "opposite":

1. Evaluate `Deny`, flag "deny" if any matched.
2. Evaluate `Allow`, flag "allow" if any matched (even if previously matched by `Deny`)
3. Evaluate flag. If flag is not set, allow it.

See the link MickeyRoush gave for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the first directive you used would work, but it would need to be in the  correct place.

```
Order Allow,Deny
<Files something.php>
Allow from zzz.zzz.zzz.zzz
</Files>
```

Notice that I removed the deny from all as it's not required.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html#order