# is it possible to load some CSS/JS/images only if requested by a specific domain

Tags: javascript, css

I am creating a custom template for a issue tracker.

Now, what I want to do is, make the CSS/JS for my template to be made available only to some domains--> ie if a web page on my domain tries to load that CSS/JS then it works-- however if a web page on any other domain tries to load that CSS/JS then it should not work.

Is it possible to do the above? How do I accomplish this?

Comment: You would need to do this at the server level. (Your server)

Comment: Is the intent to prevent others from utilizing your css/js? Like as a security feature?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your server technology, you should be able to restrict files based on IP address. So just make your files only accessible from the server (i.e. your domain) that you want. Do you have access to the server? Or you can use the htaccess (or similar) to do the same.

[.htaccess: how to restrict access to a single file by IP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604526/htaccess-how-to-restrict-access-to-a-single-file-by-ip)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. Browsers usually send an HTTP Referrer Header with the request for stylesheets, javascript files, etc. This indicates the URL from which the file was included. You can restrict access based on this header by using a htaccess file, see [this link](http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess14.shtml) or by using a server-sided language such as PHP to serve the files.

**NOTE:** HTTP headers *can* be easily faked, so this is not a secure way of achieving this. If you specify your question further, we can look at your specific use-case.