# .htaccess Restrict/Allow by IP address to specific page

Tags: .htaccess

What I'm looking for is something along the lines below but instead of restricting access to the whole domain I want to restrict only a specific page and allow certain IP's to access it. Is this possible? Everywhere I searched is only for restricting the whole site. Thank you.

```
ErrorDocument 403 http://www.domainname.com
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from 124.34.48.165
Allow from 102.54.68.123
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3604605/2060505

Comment: If it is only one page you want to protect, put one .htaccess file in that directory with the access directives and the `ErrorDocument` directive in another .htaccess file in root directory. You don't mention what's the problem, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a code like this

```
<Location /example-map>
  Order deny,allow
  deny from all
  allow from 123.12.12.12
  allow from 123.123.43.43
</Location>
```

This by the 123... the ip from the allowed ip's and /example-map the location

by RedDev

Comment: /example-map is the page name?

Comment: Correct, if you'd want to use this deny/allow for for example https://example.com/dontcomehere you'd have <location /dontcomeheere> (....) on the first line