# Restrict Url by IP?

Tags: php, .htaccess, unix

Is it possible to restrict access to a public URL to a single IP? For example, let's say I had this url:

```
www.mydomain.com/file.txt
```

I would like to parse this TXT file by another server and block everyone else from attempting to access it. Is this possible?

Comment: It certainly is, but the how depends on your web server.

Comment: Maybe a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604526/htaccess-how-to-restrict-access-to-a-single-file-by-ip)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work (obviously change the IP to the address or block you wish to allow):

```
<Location /file.txt>
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from 123.123.123.123
</Location>
```

Comment: Great - thank you! How secure is it? Is there a way for hackers to get around this?

Comment: Only if your server or the computer at that IP address is compromised. But at that point you have much larger problems. :)

Answer (score 1):

use htaccess

```
<Files "file.txt">
    Order deny, allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
    Allow from .mydomain.com
</Files>
```

Comment: Thanks @ amigura. I gave you a +1 but I'll give @John Conde accepted answer cause he was first ;)