# How to prevent brute force attack against Magento XML-RPC

Tags: security, magento, xml-rpc, magento-1.9, brute-force

I have a Magento 1.9.2 system that is currently undergoing a brute force attack against its xml-rpc endpoint from an EC2 host.

I can simply firewall the source address but that is a short term solution, since it will likely face another attack from a different address.  I would like to be able to detect these attacks automatically to lock them down.

Fail2ban is commonly used under such circumstances but in order for it to work, I understand that it must be able to find login failure messages in a log file somewhere, however Magento does not seem to be logging the failed attempts.

How can I prevent the xml-rpc endpoint being brute forced?

```
54.246.87.74 - - [20/Jul/2015:13:10:24 +0000] "POST /index.php/api/xmlrpc/ HTTP/1.1" 200 777 "-" "XML-RPC.NET"
54.246.87.74 - - [20/Jul/2015:13:10:24 +0000] "POST /index.php/api/xmlrpc/ HTTP/1.1" 200 777 "-" "XML-RPC.NET"
54.246.87.74 - - [20/Jul/2015:13:10:25 +0000] "POST /index.php/api/xmlrpc/ HTTP/1.1" 200 777 "-" "XML-RPC.NET"
54.246.87.74 - - [20/Jul/2015:13:10:26 +0000] "POST /index.php/api/xmlrpc/ HTTP/1.1" 200 777 "-" "XML-RPC.NET"
54.246.87.74 - - [20/Jul/2015:13:10:27 +0000] "POST /index.php/api/xmlrpc/ HTTP/1.1" 200 777 "-" "XML-RPC.NET"
```

Action taken so far

I've configured fail2ban with a new filter and jail to lock it down but I still don't know if this is the best solution.

filter.d/magento-xmlrpc.conf

```
[Definition]
failregex = ^<HOST> .*POST .*api\/xmlrpc\/
ignoreregex =
```

jail.local

```
[magento-xmlrpc]

enabled     = true
port        = http,https
filter      = magento-xmlrpc
logpath     = /home/user/logs/access.log
maxretry    = 20
findtime    = 30
bantime     = 600
```

Comment: Do you have many legitimate users of the API?  If not then create a whitelist for it instead.

Comment: @clockworkgeek We have one legitimate user.  Is there a way to whitelist IPs in Magento, or does it have to be done with iptables?

Comment: Actually I was thinking of doing it in `.htaccess` like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3604605/471559).