# Only allow users on page if IP address is approved

Tags: javascript, php, html

How can I make an HTML (and CSS/PHP/JavaScript) document which only allows certain IP addresses on a page?

*(I am not asking* how *to find IP address with PHP, but how to allow access to a page based on an IP address.)*

Comment: Have a look here and see if this is what you want -- http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/blockip.shtml

Comment: @ChristopherBennett This should work. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

put this on the top of your php file and update the `allowedIps` variable with the IPs that you want to allow.

```
$allowedIps = ['198.x.x.x', '200.x.x.x'];
$userIp = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

if (!in_array($userIp, $allowedIps)) {
    exit('Unauthorized');
}
```

for non PHP files (eg .html, .css) you will have to update your `.htaccess` file to add file specific permission. The following SOF thread should help: (assuming you are using apache server)

[.htaccess: how to restrict access to a single file by IP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604526/htaccess-how-to-restrict-access-to-a-single-file-by-ip)

Comment: Yes, but how would I include this in HTML?

Comment: for HTML files you will have to allow/ deny IP addresses from .htaccess file

Comment: @INTERESTING just updated my answer. Hope this will help

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want to bother with the code, put your site on Cloudflare and block ips

Answer (score 0):

Try this with PHP :

```
function CheckIPAccess() {
  //allowed IP. Change it to the IP addresses you want to allow to access your webpage

  $allowedip = '127.0.0.1';
  $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
  return ($ip == $allowedip);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, IP restrictions are done at the web-server configuration level, so that unauthorized IPs simply can't *reach* your code at all.

It would actually be quite messy to try to do this kind of check within your application – "you'd undoubtedly miss one" – but the server can easily do it for you.

(I do not recommend attempting to use IPs for privilege checking and so forth ... "IPs change.  Frequently.  Very messy.  Very ...")

Even stronger yet would be firewalls, and maybe VPNs.  You really want to keep intruders as far away as possible and to give them as little information as possible.  (For instance, why should they even be able to detect that the web-server *exists?)*  Strive to make the entire setup as "hardened" as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I tried

```html
$allowedIps = ['198.x.x.x', '200.x.x.x'];
$userIp = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

if (!in_array($userIp, $allowedIps)) {
    exit('Unauthorized');
}
```

and I get blocked by the very IP I am accessing it by. How do I fix this?